# Use python+selenium+chrome to download a pdf, change the file save path by set ChromeOptions，however only the D drive can work

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, download

When I change the file path to C drive, Chrome just save the pdf in the default download path.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {'profile.default_content_settings.popups': 1, 'download.default_directory': path_save}
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
s = Service('D:/a/pythonProject/venv/code/chromedriver.exe')
global  driver 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = s,options = options )
html1 = "https://XXXXXX"  
driver.get(html1)
```

Why the different path_save have different results？

Answer (score 0):

Ok，I get the reason. The path contain some element that python cann't recognise, the default path will be used instead.